# A Green's function for the Laplacian on k-forms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, hodge-theory

Let $X$ be a compact, oriented, Riemannian $n$-fold. Then we have a Laplacian operator $\Delta = d d^{\ast} + d^{\ast} d$ from $\Omega^k(X)$ to itself. We have the Hodge decomposition $\Omega^k(X) = \mathrm{Ker}(\Delta) \oplus d \Omega^{k-1}(X) \oplus d^{\ast} \Omega^{k+1}(X)$; these summands are called harmonic forms, exact forms and co-exact forms. The map $\Delta$ takes each summand to itself, acting by $0$ on the harmonic forms and bijectively on the other two summands. Let $\Gamma : \Omega^k(X) \to \Omega^k(X)$ be the operator which is $0$ on the harmonic forms, and which is inverse to $\Delta$ on the exact and the co-exact forms.

When $k=0$, the operator $\Gamma$ can be described explicitly using the Green's function. This is a function $G(x,y)$ on $(X \times X) \setminus (\mbox{diagonal})$ such that $\Gamma(f)(y) = \int_{x \in X} G(x,y) f(x) \ \mathrm{Vol}$, where $\mathrm{Vol}$ is the $n$-form coming from the Riemannian metric and the orientation of $X$.

> I'd like to know the analogous statement for other values of $k$.

Here is what I suspect is the answer. Recall that, if $\pi : Y \to Z$ is a proper submersion from
a $(d+e)$-fold to a $d$-fold, with oriented fibers, then we get a map $\pi_{\ast} : \Omega^{k+e}(Y) \to \Omega^k(Z)$ such that, for any $k$-dimensional cell $U$ sitting in $Z$, we have $\int_U \pi_{\ast}(\omega) = \int_{\pi^{-1}(U)} \omega$. Let $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ be the coordinate projections from $X \times X$ to $X$. Then I suspect there is some $n$-form $\gamma$ on $(X \times X) \setminus (\mbox{diagonal})$ such that $\Gamma(\omega) = (\pi_2)_{\ast} (\gamma \wedge \pi_1^{\ast} (\omega))$. If we have orthonormal eigenbases $\omega_{k,j}$ of $\Delta$ on $\Omega^k(X)$, with eigenvalues $\lambda_{k,j}$, then I expect
$$\gamma = \sum \frac{1}{\lambda_{k,j}} (\pi_1^{\ast} \omega_{k,j}) \wedge (\pi_2^{\ast} (\omega_{k,j}^{\ast})). \qquad (1)$$
Here $\omega_{k,j}^{\ast}$ is Hodge star. The letter $\gamma$ is meant to suggest that this is a generalization of the Green's function.

So first question

> Is this right? For example, does the sum in (1) converge, and in what sense?

Then the second question:

> How do I get a hold of this $n$-form $\gamma$ explicitly? Does it obey some differential equation? For example, what is it for the $n$-sphere?

I started wondering about this stuff because I wrote [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3816991/448) over on math.stackexchange about how to compute Hodge decomposition on a torus, and then I realized that I wouldn't know how to do it for a sphere. I do know how to compute the classical Green's function for a sphere; see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218272/greens-function-on-sphere).

Comment: There is a paper by Stern, Fixed Point Theorems from a de Rham Perspective, that uses "Schwarz forms" for the heat kernel (replacing your $1/\lambda$ by $e^{-t \lambda}$). Your sum seems formally correct, but I'm not sure about convergence. It also seems to me there must be some relevant abstract theorems in functional analysis about integral kernels, but I'm rusty on this. The inverse of the Laplacian is a pseudodifferential operator of order -2, of course.